# $f_n(x) =\frac{n}{2}\left(e^{\left(\frac{1}{n}-4\right)x}-e^{\left(-\frac{1}{n}-4\right)x}\right)$ - Prove uniform convergence in $[-1,1]$

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

$$f_n(x) =\frac{n}{2}\left(e^{\left(\frac{1}{n}-4\right)x}-e^{\left(-\frac{1}{n}-4\right)x}\right).$$
Need to prove uniform convergence in $[-1,1]$
I first calculated the P.W converge, which is: $e^{-4x}$
I then had to prove that it doesnt converge uniformly in $(-\infty, -1]$.
Done it, but now I have to prove in: $[-1,1]$
( then at $[1, \infty)$ - but I think I will manage it, but first I need to prove the $[-1,1]$

Comment: Is $n/2$ multiplying both exponentials or just the first one? Put some parentheses if necessary.

Comment: Are you sure about the limit ? Pług in $x=0$

Comment: oh wait, I forgot the x thingy... my mistake, sorry.
Weird I didnt get $xe^{-4x}$, I got $e^{-4x}$

About n/2, yea its for all, I will edit now, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\neq 0$, then we have
$$
f_n (x) = xe^{ - 4x} \frac{{\sinh (x/n)}}{{x/n}} \to xe^{ - 4x} 
$$
uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb R$, since if $|x|\leq M$ then
$$
\left| {\frac{{\sinh (x/n)}}{{x/n}}} \right| =\frac{{\sinh (x/n)}}{{x/n}}\le  \frac{{\sinh (M/n)}}{{M/n}}  \to 1.
$$
The case $x=0$ is obvious.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136840/discussion-on-answer-by-gary-f-nx-fracn2-lefte-left-frac1n-4-ri).